# class not found exception in servlet

Tags: classnotfoundexception

12:50:30,311 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver from [Module "deployment.santosh.war:main" from Service Module Loader]

12:50:30,311 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:191)

12:50:30,311 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:358)

12:50:30,312 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:330)

12:50:30,312 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:307)

12:50:30,312 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:101)

12:50:30,312 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)

12:50:30,313 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)

12:50:30,313 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)    at com.cluster.action.CheckServlet2.doGet(CheckServlet2.java:43)

12:50:30,313 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734)

12:50:30,313 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)

12:50:30,313 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329)

12:50:30,314 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)

12:50:30,314 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275)

12:50:30,314 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)

12:50:30,314 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)    at org.jboss.as.web.NamingValve.invoke(NamingValve.java:57)

12:50:30,314 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:154)

12:50:30,315 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)

12:50:30,315 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)

12:50:30,315 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:362)

12:50:30,315 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877)

12:50:30,316 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:667)

12:50:30,316 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:951)

12:50:30,316 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Answer (score 0):

That is because you dont have that ojdbc.jar in your classpath. Get it from [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ojdbc/ojdbc/14) add it to your classpath

Comment: ya i add ojdbc14.jar to my project path in library but still that is same error

Comment: on project name build path--> then configure build path---> then add external jar there i select ojdbc14 jar and saved.. but still thats comming same

Comment: put it under web-inf/lib

Comment: ya just i copied to lib sir thats working.... but before copy the jar in lib as i add jar to project level like only i checked to lib but that shows the ojdbc is found like.... what is the difference bettween to add jar in project level and copy the jar in lib folder... till now i havent did like this

Comment: If is it a simple java applicaton you can add it to your build path but if it is web application application you need to add it under web-inf/lib or tomcat's lib folder to be available at runtime when the war is deployed . if it worked you can accept it as your answer

Comment: but till now i havent did this type in web application... i m using the jboss7 as server.. i learned new things from you that will may help me to guide for othres thank you...